# Laravel Eloquent - Attach vs. SyncWithoutDetaching

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

What is the difference between syncWithoutDetaching and attach in Laravel?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's assume that you have auto-increment primary key `id` in your pivot table, you will notice:

1. `attach()` will add the new records to the pivot table, and pre-existed relations will get fresh ids.
2. `sync()` will remove all existed relations and set only provided in current request, with fresh ids too.
3. `syncWithoutDetaching()` will not remove all existing relations missing from the one provided in current process, then the pre-existed rows won't get new ids.

Answer (score 19):

Two things:

1. `attach()` will always add a new record to the pivot table, whereas `syncWithoutDetaching()` will only add a new record if one does not exist.

Let's say you have orders and items.

```
$order->items()->attach(1);
$order->items()->attach(1);

// $order->items()->count() === 2

$order2->items()->syncWithoutDetaching(1);
$order2->items()->syncWithoutDetaching(1);

// $order2->items()->count() === 1
```

2. `attach()` returns `null`, whereas `syncWithoutDetaching()` returns an array showing what was attached/detached/updated.

Answer (score 4):

`attach()` will add new records even if they already exist.
`sync()` will remove records that don't exist in the `sync()`, leave untouched those that already do, and add the ones that don't.
`syncWithoutDetaching()` is the same as `sync()` but doesn't remove anything.

So

```
1: Apple, 2: Banana, 3: Carrot
```

`attach(['Apple', 'Date'])` -> `1: Apple, 2: Banana, 3: Carrot, 4: Apple, 5: Date`
Note: there are two Apples

but
`sync(['Apple', 'Date'])` -> `1: Apple, 4: Date`

and
`syncWithoutDetaching(['Apple', 'Date'])` -> `1: Apple, 2: Banana, 3: Carrot, 4: Date`

`sync(Array, false)` is the same as `syncWithoutDetaching()`:

```
public function syncWithoutDetaching($ids)
    {
        return $this->sync($ids, false);
    }
```

In short, by default `sync()` detaches.